# Too many Iif - Expression too complex in query expression - Alternative solutions?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, iif

I'm trying to count if a certain criteria is met, in this instance if RB is true, it should count it.
I've got this to work the way it should, when I just had to count using a few Iif.

However the below example exceeds the amount of Iif statements allowed (Getting the Expression is too complex in query expression).

```
SELECT Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.LedningsID, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.OpstroemKnudeID, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.OpstrømsKnudeNavn, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Opstrømsdybde, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.NedstroemKnudeID, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Nedstrømsdybde, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.NedstrømsKnudeNavn, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Laengde, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Handelsmaal, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Materiale, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.TVObsKode,

Count(IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="RB",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="OB",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="PF",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="DE",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="FS",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="IS",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="RØ",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="IN",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="AF",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="BE",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="FO",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="GR",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="PH",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="PB",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="OS",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="OP",
True,IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode]="OK",
True,Null)))))))))))))))))) AS [Antal Observationer]

FROM Rorenes_tilstand, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger
GROUP BY Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.LedningsID, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.OpstroemKnudeID, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.OpstrømsKnudeNavn, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Opstrømsdybde, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.NedstroemKnudeID, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Nedstrømsdybde, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.NedstrømsKnudeNavn, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Laengde, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Handelsmaal, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.Materiale, Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.TVObsKode
ORDER BY Sanering_af_hoved_og_stikledninger.LedningsID;
```

So my question is, is there another way of doing what I specified without using Iif? The below image shows the datasheet view, which counts in Antal Observationer (when there was only a few Iif)

[image: AccessDatasheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use someting like this for [Antal Observationer] column:

```
Sum(IIf([TVObs].[TVObsKode] IN ("RB","OB","PF",..."OK"),1,0)) AS [Antal Observationer]
```

But it would be better to store the list of codes in separate table and join main query with this table

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Thank you Sergey. :)